# Sqlite not working in hybrid app

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, sqlite, monaca

I'm developing a hybrid app using Monaca IDE, the thing is the database I'm using is made in Sqlite,  and it works great in the preview,  I even had another project with the same DB scheme and it worked great too, but when I try to make the .apk, the application works but the db is never created,  I don't know if I should be doing something else that I'm not aware of, or if you guys have any idea of what might be going on here!

Note: It doesn't work either if I open the Monaca preview in firefox

this is my db code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     onDeviceReady();
});


function onDeviceReady() {
db = window.openDatabase('antel', '1.0', 'primera', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
db.transaction(crearBase);
};


function crearBase(tx) {
tx.executeSql('Create table if not exists PARADA (nombre TEXT PRIMARY KEY)', [], function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('Create table if not exists REGISTRO (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement, nomParada TEXT REFERENCES PARADA (nombre), tipo TEXT ,km TEXT,fecha TEXT,hora TEXT)', [], function (tx) {
         tx.executeSql('Create table if not exists EMAIL (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,nombre TEXT)', [], function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql('Select nombre FROM PARADA',[],meFijoSiEsVacia);});
    });
});

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Kerosene is right about how to write those statements the problem that I was having was my Jquery importation, since I had:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
```

And that way (I don't know why) it works in the preview but not in the device

when I Changed it to:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
```

Worked great!,

Thank you Kerosene, you're the only one who try to help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you need to create a callback hell like this. You should consider that you are relying that every statement is getting through fine and there is no error handling. I'm not into Monaca - so not sure which cordova SQLite plugin they're using, but I had a look at [their documentation regarding SQLite](http://docs.monaca.mobi/3.5/en/sampleapp/tips/storage/)

They are executing all statements on opening sql transaction:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    var db = window.openDatabase('antel', '1.0', 'primera', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
    db.transaction(crearBase, errorCB, successCB);
};


function crearBase(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('Create table if not exists PARADA (nombre TEXT PRIMARY KEY)');
    tx.executeSql('Create table if not exists REGISTRO (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement, nomParada TEXT REFERENCES PARADA (nombre), tipo TEXT ,km TEXT,fecha TEXT,hora TEXT)');
    tx.executeSql('Create table if not exists EMAIL (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,nombre TEXT)');
    tx.executeSql('Select nombre FROM PARADA');
}

function errorCB(err) {
    console.log("Error occured while executing SQL: "+err.code);
}

function successCB() {
    console.log("all fine");
}
```

There might be a reason you're nesting all those success functions, but you should handle also the error callbacks. Just stating "preview worked, device not" is not enough. Browser enviroment is of course different to Cordova plugins.